# Intl.NumberFormat "compact" doesn't return correctly formated number

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, ecmascript-6, number-formatting

Following this [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat) I've tried to get large numbers formatted more compact:

```
console.log(
    new Intl.NumberFormat(
        'en-GB', 
        { notation: "compact" , compactDisplay: "short" }
    ).format(987654321)
);
```

But my result, in both Firefox and Chrome, differs. I get "987,654,321" instead of the expected "988M" as in the example. Anyone know why this is the case and how I might be able to fix it?

Comment: This is happening to me as well, but only on react-native.  Does this happen to you on sites like jsfiddle?

Comment: I haven't tried jsfiddle - just noticed it during development of an extension. I ended up using https://github.com/Kocal/vue-numerals as a work around (in case it comes in handy)

Comment: In google chrome console it works as expected, outputs '988M'

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and I tried to look for a logical reason and
I found this official documentation :
https://v8.dev/features/intl-numberformat#notation
And as I understood 'compact' option it's still not fully supported

Comment: Ah, good to know. I've dropped it for https://github.com/Kocal/vue-numerals by now.

Comment: oh thanks for the link, it seems to me I will use it for my project also!

Comment: Note that that link details the status quo **in August 2019**. `compact` is supported in Firefox too, but Safari doesn't yet, it appears. You can use the https://formatjs.io/docs/polyfills/intl-numberformat polyfill in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

For react native users: adding this polyfill worked for us:

```
import "@formatjs/intl-getcanonicallocales/polyfill";

import "@formatjs/intl-locale/polyfill";

import "@formatjs/intl-pluralrules/polyfill";
import "@formatjs/intl-pluralrules/locale-data/es";

import "@formatjs/intl-numberformat/polyfill";
import "@formatjs/intl-numberformat/locale-data/es";
```